# How to set PDQPRIORITY and FET_BUF_SIZE

Tags: informix

I am very new to IBM Informix.

Trying to fetch some data from Informix on Linux machine from Windows system.

I need to set FET_BUF_SIZE and PDQPRIORITY environment variables.

Over net suggestions are to use setnet32 application that comes with IBM Informix client SDK.  Have tried it, but there is no option for PDQPRIORITY and for FET_BUF_SIZE my server people told me to set 200,000 but it not taking only 5 chars.

Any suggestions how to set these environment variables (FET_BUF_SIZE=200000 and PDQPRIORITY to 2) at client side, would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which client API are you using? ESQL/C, ODBC, or something else? And in what context are you running the code? Having asked that, I'm not sure it actually makes all that much difference. On Unix, you could consider setting `FET_BUF_SIZE 200000` in `$HOME/.informix` (and likewise PDQPRIORITY), but I'm not sure that's available as an option on Windows, not least because the equivalent of `$HOME` is not well defined on Windows, AFAIUI (but let me know if `%HOME%` is set as standard). You could also simply set them in the environment on Unix. If you can control the environment of the app, try it.

Comment: I am using IBM Data Server Driver Package, which comes with a utility setnet32 (win app) to set the environment.  But that utility does not have option to set PDQPRIORITY.